# Using ArcGIS Runtime .NET for services

Tags: arcgis

Is it allowed to build a .NET service for ReverseGeoCoding (LocalLocatorTask) which runs on a server?

We would like to build a service which translates GPS-coordinates to addresses using ArcGIS  Runtime SDK for .NET. We are already licensed to use the Standard license needed for LocalLocators.

But now we've heard is not allowed to build server applications, is this true and where can I find this in the terms and conditions?

Thanks,
Frederiek

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't allowed (though I can't find the exact wording) as it basically negates the need for ArcGIS Server or the need for multiple user accounts when the same functionality is deployed as an app.

If you can't use it as an app or use ArcGIS Server / Online directly and really need a windows service then you will need to write your own code to do it. If you can use ArcGIS Server services from the windows service I have a project that manages the REST calls at https://github.com/davetimmins/ArcGIS.PCL

Comment: If I read the license agreement correctly, it states you need a server license for server deployments of esri software. The Runtime does not have server licenses, so there you go.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently prohibited by the license agreement, though there is no technical reason why it wouldn't work. It is not tested or certified for services environments by Esri development teams.